# Почему во View не передается модель?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть страница

```
@model MyProj.WebUI.Models.ProductsListViewModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<span>@this.Model.ToString();</span> // 6
```

В последней строке возникает exception

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]    ASP._Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml.Execute() in
>   c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Views\Home\Index.cshtml:6
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +252
>   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +146
>   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +88
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +106
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>   +374

Нome контроллер у меня такой

```
public class HomeController : BaseController{
        private IProductRepository _repository;
        public HomeController(IProductRepository productRepository)
        {
            this._repository = productRepository;
        }

        [CustomAuthorize]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

Где прописывается связка Контроллер-Модель?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Где прописывается связка Контроллер-Модель?

```
return View(model);
```

Например:

```
public ActionResult Index(int page = 1)
{
    if (page < 1) page = 1;

    IList<Product> products = _repository.GetAll( skip: (page-1) * PAGE_SIZE,
                                                  take:PAGE_SIZE );

    var model = new ProductsListViewModel{
        Products = products,
        PageInfo = new PageInfo {
            CurrentPage = page,
            TotalItems = _repository.Count(),
            PageSize = PAGE_SIZE
        };
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: ммм, ещё вопрос (тот же но по-другому), хорошо, мы зашли на страницу допустим `index.cshtml`, в странице указано `@model MyProj.WebUI.Models.ProductsListViewModel`, как модель ProductsListViewModel, знает какой контроллер нужно брать? Или контроллер в cshtml нужно указать?

Comment: @nick_n_a, модель ничего не знает, ее просто передают (= метод `Controller.View` возвращает по умолчанию вьюху из `~/Views/ИМЯ_КОНТРОЛЛЕРА/ИМЯ_ЭКШНА.cshtml`. Можно первым параметром передать строку с имемем вьюхи: `View("AnotherView", model)`

Comment: Спасибо, дошло ИМЯ_КОНТРОЛЛЕРАController.cs берётся для контроллера, а для модели, нужно сделать `View(new MyModel1())` в контроллере и в cshtml ещё и указать `@model MyModel1`.

Comment: @nick_n_a, еще уточнение. Вьюха - это ответ, который возвращается из контроллера. Грубо говоря, мы заходим не на страницу, а "на контроллер". А тем, в какой контроллер и какой экшн мы поситим, управляет **роутинг**, который из строки запроса ищет подходящий контроллер и экшн.