# MVC модель, как "протащить" свойство по всем моделям (или по всей программе)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть проект на ef + mvc. C красивыми контроллер + 30 моделей + n-вью Понадобилось на всех страницах (Views) написать имя фирмы. Получается...  нужно во все модели вносить изменения, и не просто изменения, а и связывать их с репозиторием (IRepository), так как имя компании хранится в `IQueryable<Company> companies` из репозитория-СУБД (часть моделей связаны часть нет)? Нет ли пути по-проще? Нужно всё сделать через глобальную модель... или для таких случаев есть механизм "глобальности"? Возможно это нужно не через модель делать...

Теперь более детально. База данных подключена через EF, в контроллеры она подключена через конструктор, например

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    private IProductRepository _repository;
    public HomeController(IProductRepository productRepository)
    {
        this._repository = productRepository;
    }
}
```

Часть вью подключены отдельные таблицы репозитория `IQueryable`. На главной (Home) странице выбирается фирма. Я это реализовал так:

```
    @model MyProj.WebUI.Models.ProductsListViewModel
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
    ...
   @foreach(var item in Model.Companies){     
         <h1 style="font-family:'Lobster';color:white">
             <a style="font-size:x-large;color:blue;" href="/Menu?c=@item.Id">@item.Name</a>
         </h1>     
   }
```

Поскольку пользователям можно выбирать любую фирму, я не стал шифровать id или делать post-запросом (это не столь важно, всеравно в Request попадёт).

Ставлю себе задачу. У меня есть на главной странице меню. После выбора "фирмы" мне нужно отображать её имя на других страницах. Хранить имя фирмы буду в `Request["c"]`. Далее чуть о решении. Я проверю поддерживает ли модель свойство Companies, если да - я сохраняю имя и id компании, дальше, из "кеша" буду выводить их. Скорее всего через ViewBag.

Незнаю можно ли решить эту задачу в "общем" виде. Я уже "наметил" себе решение, позже опубликую. Думаю с похожей задачей кто-нибудь ещё столкнется.

Comment: есть ViewBag c:

Comment: Глобальность - это моветон. Для статической информации есть механизмы компоновок (_layouts_) и частичных представлений (_partial views_).

Comment: @free_ze  Layout.cshtml  я нашёл (подключен через layout). Я могу сделать из layouts вызов `@MyProj.f(x)` где x это или HttpContext или Model, но они не содержат IRepository, как добраться до базы, что б во все модели не лепить DataSet-ы или коннекты?

Comment: [жизненный цикл обработки запроса в mvc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application/_static/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application1.pdf) _(2я страница, особенно зеленую диаграмму)_ изучите, и попробуйте выяснить как выполнить некоторое действие (извлечение информации о названии из БД перед всеми действиями контроллеров). Когда вытащите данные, запихаете во viewBag, как выше написали. Либо через базовый класс вью-модели

Comment: @nick_n_a, сообщество сможет вам помочь, если вы дополните вопрос кратким экскурсом в архитектуру вашего приложения через все слои: от схемы базы данных, до представлений. Сейчас же непонятно, скажем, почему бы банально не положить ваши данные в источник данных (базу)? Действительно ли вам нужно имя фирмы подгружать _динамически_ из источника данных? И таких вопросов будет немало, ибо мы вынуждены гадать о том, что у вас и как там устроено.

Comment: еще вывести можно с помощью `@Html.RenderAction()` во вьюшке. Возможно с учетом кэширования результатов экшена это будет самый простой вариант.

Comment: @free_ze дак классический mvc там. у человека вопрос в том, как вытаскивать одно и то же значение из БД в каждом контроллере и каждом экшене, и как это выводить, чтобы не повторять код десятки раз

Comment: @teran, если вы сегодня дежурная Ванга, то может тогда вы расскажите мне?) Здравый смысл подсказывает, что вытаскивать одно и то же значение на все вьюхи не нужно и даже вредно. Что MVC понятно, только ТС нужно вносить правки, суть которых не ясна.

Comment: @free_ze дак вот и топик стартеру он то же самое подсказывает, поэтому он и создал вопрос.

Comment: хотя еще вариант - в случае если надо писать название фирмы залогиненного пользователя, то эта инфа помещается в сессию, и оттуда выводится.

Comment: @teran, разница в том, что он-то знает, что ему нужно, а мы с вами сейчас  гадаем)

Comment: Насчёт сессии я уже думал. Зная особенности MVC я вижу написание статической `f(HttpContext, Model)`.

Comment: Спасибо за коментарии, теперь я знаю про ViewBag, layout и хорошо понимаю что к чему, что б решить эту задачу. Мне осталось собрать всё в кучу.

Comment: такие вещи в сессиях хранят, не изобретайте велосипедов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получилось.   Используя layout (очень помог @free_ze) можно вызывать метод контроллера (который связан с субд).

Контроллер поддерживает Action, его доработал так:

```
public class MenuController : BaseController
{
    [ActionName("GetCompany")]
    public System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString GetCompany() {
        int id = 0;
        return new MvcHtmlString(
                 int.TryParse(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request["c"]??"", out id)
              ? _repository.Companies.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == id).Name
              : "unknown");                        
       }
}
```

Теперь добавляю в View из _layout.cshtml вызов на GetCompany

```
<a href="\" style="color: white">@Html.Action("GetCompany","Menu")</a>
```

Соответственно _layout можно получить из свойства Layout текущей страницы, как правило вверху например index.cshtml

```
 @model MyProj.WebUI.Models.ProductsListViewModel
 @{
   ViewBag.Title = "Index";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }
```

Пожалуй это заготовка что бы просто показать как добавить свойство на все страницы. По хорошему, при срыве сессии нужно делать редирект, и возможно ещё что-то можно допилить.

Так же помогло
  [Почему во View не передается модель?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736706/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be-view-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c/736707)

Возможно понадобится [Жизненный цикл ASP MVC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application/_static/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application1.pdf)

Comment: В C# даже массивы аллоцируются в хипе, поэтому `= new string[0];` должного эффекта ни то, что не даст, а еще и потребует лишней аллокации. Зато у `List<T>`, есть конструктор, который позволяет резервивать буфер необходимого размера.

Comment: И, простите, это выглядит, как отвратительный костыль: это нельзя тестировать, ибо MVC пошло к черту, даже вью-модель знает про http-контекст, откуда вы руками извлекаете значения(!!!), используется глобальное состояние, метод, вызываемый **для всех вьюх** шаблона и вот эта жесть с блокировками, да еще и `ViewBag` динамический, который в общем-то не рекомендуют использовать. Это сборник антипаттернов.

Comment: В ASP.NET MVC это нужно было оформить как child action и звать напрямую, без вот этого вот трешака.

Comment: Никаких статиков! Если у вас есть в модели есть `List<Company> Companies`, почему не взять имя оттуда?

Comment: Вы уже тащите список объектов-компаний внутри модели, здесь можно было пофильтровать его попутно: `Companies.First(c => c.Id == id).Name`.

Comment: С этим мне понятно. А вот как убрать HttpContext - незнаю, в том или ином виде он останется.

Comment: Внутри экшна работать с HTTP еще терпимо, поэтому можете юзать его там. Если модели у вас не всегда компании содержат, то, да, придется брать из БД отдельным запросом. Когда будут проблемы с производительностью - прикрутите кэш.

Comment: Вы неправильно его зовёте.